# Magento 2.2.4: Homepage missing from Sitemap.xml

Tags: seo, sitemaps, magento2.2.4

I'm encountering an issue where the homepage is missing entirely from the sitemap.xml file.  In previous versions, it was included as `/home` which was identified as a duplicate content issue and corrected by:

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12446
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/7e43513c7af1b7dee314037a9d46db67be0fd38a

These commits appear to exclude 3 pages from the sitemap.xml, home, 404, and cookie restriction. However, while trying to solve removing `/home` from the sitemap, we removed the homepage all together. I don't believe this to be expected behavior, but maybe I'm missing something?

Can anyone provide insight into how to get the homepage as `examplesite.com` within the sitemap.xml file, and separately maybe explain the intention behind the above commits?